# AttributeError: 'File' object has no attribute 'model'

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I a having following setup in which my Model classes look like following

```
from django.db import models
from User.models import UserProfile


class Advertisement(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='advertisements', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False, default='')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False, default='')
    rent = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    no_of_bedrooms = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    no_of_bathrooms = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    posted_by = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    date_ad_posted = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=13, blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=False)
    security_deposit = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Advertisement, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class File(models.Model):
    Ad = models.ForeignKey(Advertisement, related_name='ad-photo', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False)
    remark = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and my serializers look like following

```
class AdvertisementSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.email')

    class Meta:
        model = Advertisement
        fields = ('id', 'owner', 'title', 'location', 'rent', 'status', 'no_of_bedrooms', 'no_of_bathrooms',
                  'date_ad_posted', 'posted_by', 'contact', 'description')
        kwargs = {
            'url': {'view_name': 'advertisement-detail'}
        }


class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = ('Ad', 'file', 'remark', 'timestamp')
```

i am registering my model in admin.py in following way

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Advertisement, AdContract, File


class FileInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = File


class PropertyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [FileInline, ]


admin.site.register(Advertisement, File)
admin.site.register(AdContract)
```

but upon making migrations i am getting following error
[image]

i have tried a few solutions i got after googling but the error is still there. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To register multiple models at once you need to pass them as iterable:

```
admin.site.register([Advertisement, File])
```

instead of

```
admin.site.register(Advertisement, File)
```

Answer (score 4):

`admin.site.register` is used to register a model class with an admin class.

This is it's function signature:
`AdminSite.register(model_or_iterable, admin_class=None, **options)`

In you `admin.py` you're passing File model instead of the your custom admin class: `admin.site.register(Advertisement, File)`

Try this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Advertisement, AdContract, File


class FileInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = File


class PropertyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [FileInline, ]


admin.site.register(File, FileInline)
admin.site.register(AdContract)
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem. Like you, I was registering the `Model`, not the `admin` model.

Try This:

```
 admin.site.register(File, FileInLine)
```